# Testing: Getting the payload of the response from a Promise object

Tags: javascript, promise, redux, redux-promise, redux-promise-middleware

In my `React-redux` app, one of my action creators `returns` like this:

```
return {
        type : GET_RESULTS,
        payload: response
    };
```

I am trying to write a test where I just call the action creator externally and mock its arguments since its just a pure function.

In my app, the middleware `redux-promise` directly handles the promise to payload conversion in the store and passes it to the reducers.

The issue is that, the `payload` in the above returned object is a `promise` returned by `axios GET` call. So, in my test file, where I call it, I will get a `promise`, but I need to get its real payload value, the one after the `promise` is complete.

How do I do this?

Comment: use the standard promise's `.then` method

Comment: Oh.. I am very new to promises, I am unsure exactly how the async nature of the promise will affect my test. But I hope my question was clear.
Assuming I have an `action`, I am going to explicitly call the `action` as a function and then use its `promise` object to get the resolved value. Will it work in this case?